# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hoc_sinh_dang_nhap' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, arrays, variables, undefined, local

P/S: The text in my code is vietnamese, if you are a foreign, you can use Google Translate to understand.

```
#1. Khởi tạo mảng và biến
ten = []
cac_cot_diem =[]
diem_trung_binh = []
thu_tu = 0
so_cot_diem = 0
so_hoc_sinh = 0
cot_diem_dang_nhap = 1
hoc_sinh_dang_nhap = 1
ten_hoc_sinh = 0

def chao_mung():
    print("<--Chào mừng đến với AvCalculator-->\nPhiên bản 0.1\nBởi Nguyễn Minh Trí - 6A4 - THCS Hoa Lư\n_______________________________________________")
    nhap_du_lieu()
def nhap_du_lieu():
    so_cot_diem = input("Vui lòng nhập số cột điểm: ")
    so_hoc_sinh = input("Vui lòng nhập số học sinh: ")
    print("Vậy là bạn sẽ nhập",so_cot_diem,"cột điểm cho",so_hoc_sinh,"học sinh.")
    while hoc_sinh_dang_nhap <= so_hoc_sinh:
        ten_hoc_sinh = input("Nhập tên học sinh thứ ", hoc_sinh_dang_nhap)
        ten.append(ten_hoc_sinh)
        return ten_hoc_sinh
        hoc_sinh_dang_nhap = hoc_sinh_dang_nhap + 1
def tinh_diem_trung_binh():
    # 2. Đi qua từng phần tử trong mảng
    for diem in cac_cot_diem:
        total = 0
        # 3. Tính điểm của 1 học sinh
        for value in diem:
            total = total + value
        diem_trung_binh = total / len(trials)
        diem_trung_binh.append(diem_trung_binh)
        #4. Hiển thị điểm lên màn hình
        while thu_tu < len(scores):
            print("Diem so cua",name[count],"la", scores[count])
            thu_tu = thu_tu + 1
chao_mung()
```

My code is an average calculator for teachers to calculate. As you can see in the code.

The output is:

```
<--Chào mừng đến với AvCalculator-->
Phiên bản 0.1
Bởi Nguyễn Minh Trí - 6A4 - THCS Hoa Lư
_______________________________________________
Vui lòng nhập số cột điểm: 10
Vui lòng nhập số học sinh: 10
Vậy là bạn sẽ nhập 10 cột điểm cho 10 học sinh.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tris\My Coding Way\Nothing.py", line 37, in <module>
    chao_mung()
  File "D:\Tris\My Coding Way\Nothing.py", line 14, in chao_mung
    nhap_du_lieu()
  File "D:\Tris\My Coding Way\Nothing.py", line 19, in nhap_du_lieu
    while hoc_sinh_dang_nhap <= so_hoc_sinh:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hoc_sinh_dang_nhap' referenced before assignment
```

Thank you very much for your helping!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell the function that you are using a global variable.

```py
def nhap_du_lieu():
    global hoc_sinh_dang_nhap
```